# How to customise script to work on individual pages

Tags: javascript

I've been given code by an advertiser to place on my site but it's not working. Usually I can pasta  script from an advertiser and it just works, could someone help me to figure out what this is missing to work.

I have the following code provided by them. I have removed the API KEY

```
<div id="ffm_widget"></div>
<script>
window.featureFM_PassBack = function () {
// PUT YOUR PASSBACK CODE HERE
}
window.featureFM=function(e,t,n){var r,a,i=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];if(!e.getElementById(n))return a=e.createElement(t),a.id=n,a.src="//cdn.feature.fm/widgets/init.js",i.parentNode.insertBefore(a,i),window.featureFM||(r={_e:[],ready:function(e){r._e.push(e)}})}(document,"script","featurefm-widgets"),featureFM_renderWidget=function(e){function t(t){if(e.debug_mode)try{console.log(t)}catch(n){}finally{return}}featureFM.api.setApiKey(e.api_key),featureFM.api.registerNewConsumer(null,null,null,function(n,r){if(n)return void t("Feature.fm - Couldn't register a consumer, please contactfeature.fm support");try{featureFM.api.setConsumer(r.consumer_token),featureFM.api.showWebWidget(e.container_id,e.layout,e.placement, e.keywords, e.passback, e.restrictedPlatform == 'mobile' ? true : false, e.restrictedPlatform == 'web' ? true : false)}catch(a){t(a)}finally{return}})},featureFM.ready=function(){featureFM_renderWidget({api_key:"API KEY HIDDEN", container_id:"ffm_widget",placement: "default-placement", layout: 'grid',keywords : ["edm", "electronica/dance", "rap/hip hop", "soul/r&b", "fuxwithit.com"],debug_mode:false, passback: featureFM_PassBack, restrictedPlatform: 'none'})};
</script>
```

Comment: Since this is calling //cdn.feature.fm/widgets/init.js, it might be an issue with CORS, are there any errors in the console? - You might also want to contact contactfeature.fm support.

Comment: If the code isn't working you should contact the vendor and submit a help ticket.